# AD FS OpenID connect userinfo endpoint returns only sub

Tags: openid-connect, userinfo, adfs4.0

I'm currently having trouble getting user-info after successful sign-in with AD FS.
I setup my AD FS server and Web App by following Microsoft documentation.

token and access token after successful sign-in

[image: token and access token after successful sign-in]

I've also created relying party trust and claims provider and added scope to client and authUrl but nothing changed. The scope in the response body always remained openid, I ticked profile, email and openid in the settings.

```
const client = new oneLoginIssuer.Client({
      client_id: configService.get<string>('CLIENT_ID'),
      client_secret: configService.get<string>('CLIENT_SECRET'),
      redirect_uris: [configService.get<string>('REDIRECT_URI')],
      response_types: ['code id_token'],

    });

this.client.authorizationUrl({
      scope: 'profile openid email',
      response_mode: 'form_post',
      nonce: this.nonce,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that's by design.No idea why.

It's been like this for a while - at least since 2016!